# Which way is better when insert a record to the database using id generator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Because my project may be adapted to mysql or oracle,so I have a method that to produce id .When insert a new student record, the student  record should call the method to produce the id. But what I'm curious about is when to call the method.Now my project is build by spring cloud. I should call the method in service module and pass the student object with id to the dao module. Or I pass the student object and the in the dao module,I call the  id generator?
Which way is better?

Comment: Does result of id generator metod depend on database state?

Comment: @jker,no,may be mysql id can be auto-increment,oracle id can be generate by sequence.So I  did the same thing  to write a common method.People can call the method and do not need to think the database type.

Comment: In my opinion a better way would be to generate id inside dao, because you need id to save object in database, so you have to be sure that id is generated. Moreover generating id inside dao follow low coupling principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've decided to extend my comment.

In my opinion a better way would be to generate id inside dao, because you need id to save object in database, so you have to be sure that id is generated. For example if you have multiple clients and each client can save to database object student it would be difficult to make sure that each client uses id generator method in proper way. If you would use this method you don't need to take care about validation of id.

Moreover generating id inside dao follow low coupling principle.